# downloading and using gmp Xcode 4.4

Tags: c++, gmp

I have seen other questions relating to this but I'm having trouble with the basics. My computer and programming knowledge is very limited, please bear with me.

I am using Xcode4.4 for c++ on a MacBook Pro and I'm trying to use the gmp library. I have gone to the gmp site:  http://gmplib.org and have clicked on the download gmp-5.1.tar.lz but what is downloaded seems very cryptic and I'm not sure on how to proceed. I know that once you've got the library on your computer you can then link it into your project and use header files to use the library. I am also not sure how to do this.

Could anyone walk me through the process of downloading the gmp library and then using it in a c++ project on Xcode?

Any other comments/advice on this would also be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Using a package manager (homebrew, macports, fink, etc) is a much simpler way to install libraries. If you really want to do it yourself, the first thing to do is extract the archive, which I thought your Mac would do by default after clicking on it. If not, open a terminal, go to the directory that contains the downloaded file, and type `tar xf gmp-5.1.tar.lz`. That requires you to have the lzip program on your computer (not sure Mac has it by default). If it worked, enter the new directory gmp-5.1, and do `./configure --enable-cxx && make && sudo make install` and wait.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't think I have the lzip programme as I get the error: unrecognised archive format. I searched for an lzip download but ended up downloading izip which doesn't seem to help. Do you know of a good site to download lzip from?

Comment: Those same package managers I mentioned would install it in a few seconds. Otherwise, you'll need to download the source, run `tar xf lzip-1.13.tar.gz` (don't take the sources that end in `.lz` ;-), `cd` into the new directory and run `./configure && make && sudo make install`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I still can't seem to get it working. I installed macports to try and simplify my life like you suggest. (I installed macports but can't seem to find it on my mac). How would you install the gmp library using macports? Also is the gmp-5.1.1.tar.lz the right link to use from the gmp page? Thanks a lot for your time.